# Sets of integers with few sums

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Let $S$ be a finite set of integers. Denote by $S^{\leq k}$ the set $\{a_1+\dots+a_\ell : \ell\leq k, a_1,\dots,a_\ell\in S\}$ of sums of at most $k$ elements from $S$. What are best/worst cases for the size of $S^{\leq k}$ in function of $|S|$ and $k$? A trivial upper bound on this number is $|S|^k$. But we can do exponentially better: if $S$ is an arithmetic progression, then we have $|S^{\leq k}| = O(k^2 |S|)$. What other kinds of bounds can we achieve asymptotically? Can we achieve something that is linear in $k$ and $|S|$?

Comment: The interval $[\min(S^{\leq k}), \max(S^{\leq k})]\cap \Bbb Z$ grows linearly in $k$, so $|S^{\leq k}|$ is asymptotically linear in $k$.

Comment: @Arthur: This is true, but this gives a bound in terms of $k, \min(S)$ and $\max(S)$. So we cannot really compare it to the bound $|S|^k$, I guess.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you want your big-Oh to be uniform over all choices of $S$? Also, what variable are you letting tend to infinity? As per a general upper bound: $S' = \{1, (k+1), (k+1)^2, (k+1)^3, \ldots, (k+1)^{k-1}\}$ attains the trivial upper bound $|S|^k$.

Comment: The upper bound is not quite $|S|^k $, because commutativity means some sums coincide. The actual upper bound would be $\binom {|S| + k -1}{k} $, the number of choices of $k $ summands from $S $ with repetition. D Poole's construction achieves this upper bound. The lower bound is given by an arithmetic progression, which has $k (|S|-1) + 1$ distinct sums.

Comment: @DPoole The big-Oh notation $O(f(k,n))$ would mean "There exist $C, k_0,$ and $n_0$ such that for all $k\geq k_0$ and $S$ with $|S|\geq n_0$, we have $|S^{\leq k}| \leq C\cdot f(k,|S|)$." So indeed the bound should be uniform across all the sets of a given size.

Comment: @Shagnik: thanks for your comment. I guess the question was not precise enough to have a definite answer. But you certainly answered many interrogations I had, and I think it would be nice if your comments were turned into answers.

Comment: @Shagnik Ahh, yes! I forgot about commutativity. To zarathustra: Here the notation means that, but often the condition is given by context. For instance, I often look at a case where for $k$ fixed and $n \to \infty$, some expression is $O(n^k)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower bound is attained by arithmetic progressions containing $0$, which have $|S^{\le k}| = k(|S|-1)+1$. Moreover, any set attaining this lower bound must be an arithmetic progression.

Freiman's theorem, one of the highlights of additive combinatorics, gives stability for this result, saying that any set $S $ with $|S + S| \le C|S|$ must be close to a generalised arithmetic progression.  This means that, in some sense, being similar to an arithmetic progression is the only reason a set should have only a linear number of sums.

For the upper bound, note that commutativity of addition implies that the order within the $k$-tuple of summands doesn't matter. Hence the number of sums is at most the number of selections of at most $k $ elements from $S $ with repetition, which is $\binom {|S|+k}{k} $.

As observed by D Poole, you can construct sets attaining this bound (that is, without any nontrivial relations between the sums) by taking, 
$S = \{ 1, b, b^2, b^3, ..., b^{|S|-1} \} $, where $b\ge k $. Writing the sums in base-$b $, we find that the choice of summands is uniquely determined by the digits of the sum.

Here of course the set $S$ depends on $k $.  If we instead think of $S$ as being fixed and $k$ large, then note that $S^{\le k} \subseteq [\min (0,k \min S), \max (0, k \max S)]$, so that gives an alternative upper bound that is linear in $k $ (rather than the previous one, which is polynomial (with degree $|S|$)).

Comment: Thanks for that answer and the useful reference to Freiman's theorem.